# Google Tag Manager Losing Checkout Steps

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I made a custom GTM to track checkout steps. I am using custom JS variable to populate the ecommerce object.

I am getting step 1 into my GA but not other options although in preview mode I see the code firing correctly.

The checkout process is as this:

example.com/cart - Send step 1 by GTM (track type - event, trigger - URL)
example.com/checkout - Send step 2 by GTM (track type - event, trigger - URL)

Step 3 triggers when element #shipping is visible (track type - event, trigger - element visibility, **non-interaction hit - FALSE**)

Step 4 triggers when element #payment is visible (track type - event, trigger - element visibility, **non-interaction hit - FALSE**)

The elements are visible when user clicks on NEXT STEP

Tags are configured to use custom JS variable instead of data layer
Enhanced ecommerce is enabled in GA and in tag as well
Overriding is enabled as well in tag

thanks for any help

## Step 1

[image: Step 1]

## Step 2

[image: Step 2]

## Step 3

[image]

## Step 4

[image: Step 4 custom JS variable]

Answer (score 0):

Your steps after the first step needs to be written as:

```
‘event’: ‘checkoutOption’,
‘e-commerce: {
‘checkout_option’: {
‘actionField’: {‘step’: 2, ‘option’: ‘shipping’
```

Note the addition of Option on event and ecommerce section signaling the additional portion of checkout not a new checkout

Comment: this didnt help

Comment: Can you add a picture of the tag set up?